# Hilbert space via isomorphism

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, vector-space-isomorphism

Assume that $\mathcal H$ is isomorphic to a Hilbert space $\mathcal G$ by an application $\Phi$, which means that $\Phi$ is an isomorphism (in linear operator sense) between $\mathcal H$ and $\mathcal G$.

Define the inner product on $\mathcal H$ as
$$
\left< \Phi(x), \Phi(y) \right>_{\mathcal H} = \left< x, y\right>_{\mathcal G}
$$

Can we conclude that $\mathcal H$ is also a Hilbert space?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep, this can be called "pulling back" the Hilbert space structure on $G$ to $H$. You can go through and confirm that all the Hilbert space axioms will hold on $H$, but each proof will look the same, in that it will resolve to the fact that the axiom is true on $G$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer